# Keep rows of group if group has certain value looking at previous value

Tags: r, dataframe

For each student `id` I would like to check if they ever passed the test after failing first.

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4), homework = c('fail', 'fail', 'pass', 'fail', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass'), 
           date = c('20200122', '20200124', '20200126', '20210214', '20210216', '20210303', '20201203', '20201205')) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%Y%m%d'))

# id homework       date
# 1  1     fail 2020-01-22
# 2  1     fail 2020-01-24
# 3  1     pass 2020-01-26
# 4  2     fail 2021-02-14
# 5  2     pass 2021-02-16
# 6  3     pass 2021-03-03
# 7  4     pass 2020-12-03
# 8  4     pass 2020-12-05
```

If so, I would like to keep the rows of that student:

```
# id homework       date
# 1  1     fail 2020-01-22
# 2  1     fail 2020-01-24
# 3  1     pass 2020-01-26
# 4  2     fail 2021-02-14
# 5  2     pass 2021-02-16
```

I can't seem to find out how to 'reach' the row above/underneath inside a group in-order to make the check. Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::lead` to access rows before and after the current row respectively.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    passed_after_fail = homework == "pass" & lag(homework) == "fail"
  ) %>%
  filter(any(passed_after_fail))
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, each group just has to contain both 'fail' and 'pass'. An option using `filter()` could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter('fail' %in% homework &
         'pass' %in% homework)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id homework date      
#   <dbl> <chr>    <date>    
# 1     1 fail     2020-01-22
# 2     1 fail     2020-01-24
# 3     1 pass     2020-01-26
# 4     2 fail     2021-02-14
# 5     2 pass     2021-02-16
```